# ACL security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, acl, spring-cache

I am having issues setting up ACL through Java config in a Spring Boot application. I have created one small project to reproduce the issues.

I have tried a few different approaches. First issue I had was with EhCache, and after I fixed that (I assume I did) I couldn't login any more, and it looks like all the data is gone.

There are 4 classes with different configurations:

```
ACLConfig1.class
ACLConfig2.class
ACLConfig3.class
ACLConfig4.class
```

All `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations are working as expected, except `hasPermission`.

Controller holds 4 endpoints: one for User, one for Admin, one Public and the last one which gives me headache `@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject,'administration')")`

I am pretty sure that inserts in DB are correct. This class is one of four, the last one that I have tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class ACLConfig4 {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;


@Bean
public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
    return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(), permissionGrantingStrategy(), aclAuthorizationStrategy());
}

@Bean
public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean() {
    EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
    ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(aclCacheManager().getObject());
    ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
    return ehCacheFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
    ConsoleAuditLogger consoleAuditLogger = new ConsoleAuditLogger();
    return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(consoleAuditLogger);
}

@Bean
public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"));
}

@Bean
public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache(), aclAuthorizationStrategy(), new ConsoleAuditLogger());
}

@Bean
public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
    JdbcMutableAclService service = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    return service;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    return new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
}

@Bean
public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
    expressionHandler.setPermissionCacheOptimizer(new AclPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclService()));
    return expressionHandler;
}


}
```

What am I missing here? Why I have no data if I use ACLConfig3.class or
ACLConfig4.class. Is there any example on how this should be configured programmatically in Spring Boot?

Comment: I was a bit baffled by your question. Is `@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject,'administration')")` not working your only problem?

Comment: @xnakos, Idealy data needs to be cached. When administration will work should be easy setup read and write privileges trough DB

Comment: @5er Could you share sample database entries to authorize the user on data objects for specific actions? I really need help on a [similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872192/access-is-always-denied-in-spring-security-denyallpermissionevaluator?noredirect=1#comment72145872_41872192).

Comment: Are there any good links for implementing ACL in Spring Boot with postgre

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why you have no data was a bit tricky to find out. As soon as you define a `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` bean in your config, there is no data in the database tables. This is because your `data.sql` file isn't executed.

Before explaining why `data.sql` isn't executed I'd first like to point out that you're not using the file as intended.

`data.sql` is executed by spring-boot after hibernate has been initialized and normally only contains DML statements. Your `data.sql` contains both DDL (schema) statements and DML (data) statements. This isn't ideal as some of your DDL statements clash with hibernate's `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` behaviour (note that spring-boot uses 'create-drop' when an embedded `DataSource` is being used). You should put your DDL statements in `schema.sql` and your DML statements in `data.sql`. As you're manually defining all tables you should disable `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` (by adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to `applciation.properties`).

That being said, let's take a look at why `data.sql` isn't executed.

The execution of `data.sql` is triggered via an `ApplicationEvent` that's fired via a `BeanPostProcessor`. This `BeanPostProcessor` (`DataSourceInitializedPublisher`) is created as a part of spring-boot's Hibernate/JPA auto configuration (see `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`,  `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher` and `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer`).

Normally the `DataSourceInitializedPublisher` is created before the (embedded) `DataSource` is created and everything works as expected but by defining a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` the normal bean creation order alters.
As you've configured `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, your're automatically importing `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`.

spring-security related beans are created early on. As your `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` requires a `DataSource` for the ACL stuff and the spring-security related beans require your custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, the `DataSource` is created earlier than usual; in fact it's created so early on that spring-boot's `DataSourceInitializedPublisher` isn't created yet.
The `DataSourceInitializedPublisher` is created later on but as it didn't notice the creation of a `DataSource` bean, it also doesn't trigger the execution of `data.sql`.

**So long story short: the security configuration alters the normal bean creation order which results in `data.sql` not being loaded.**

I guess that fixing the bean creation order would do the trick, but as I don't now how (without further experimentation) I propose the following solution: manually define your `DataSource` and take care of data initialization.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                 //as your data.sql file contains both DDL & DML you might want to rename it (e.g. init.sql)
                .addScript("classpath:/data.sql")
                .build();
    }
}
```

As your data.sql file contains  all DDL required by your application you can disable `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. Add  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to `applciation.properties`.

When defining your own `DataSource` spring-boot's `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` normally back's out but if you want to be sure you can also exclude it (optional).

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This should fix your 'no data' problem. But in order to get everything working as expected you need to make 2 more modifications.

First of all, you should only define one `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` bean. Currently you're defining 2 `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` beans. Spring-security won't know which one to use and will (silently) use it's own internal `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` instead. See `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration#setMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MyACLConfig {

    //...
    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler securityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        securityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
        securityExpressionHandler.setPermissionCacheOptimizer(new AclPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclService()));
        return securityExpressionHandler;
    }

}
```

The last thing you need to do is make the `getId()` method in Car public.

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    //...    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //...
}
```

The standard `ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy` will look for a public method 'getId()' when trying to determine an object's identity during ACL permission evaluation.

*(Note that I've based my answer upon `ACLConfig4`.)*

Comment: Thank you @Pieter, its working like a it should. It seems like the biggest issue was DataBase settings. MethodSecurityExpressionHandler  bean and missing public method in Car was totally my negligence :(. BTW I didnt know that I was using *data.sql* incorrectly, Where is that specified? How did you know it? From which documentation?  Thank you.

Comment: I actually learned it by digging in to the code trying to resolve your issue but it turns out it's also mentioned in the documentation. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc