# Access is Always Denied in Spring Security - DenyAllPermissionEvaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, acl

I have configured ACL in my Spring Boot application. The ACL configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class ACLConfigration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
        return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(), permissionGrantingStrategy(), aclAuthorizationStrategy());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(aclCacheManager().getObject());
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
        return ehCacheFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
        ConsoleAuditLogger consoleAuditLogger = new ConsoleAuditLogger();
        return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(consoleAuditLogger);
    }

    @Bean
    public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
        return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"));
    }

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache(), aclAuthorizationStrategy(), new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        return new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        return new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
        expressionHandler.setPermissionCacheOptimizer(new AclPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclService()));
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

References:

- [SO Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609874/acl-security-in-spring-boot)
- [SO Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292431/how-to-configure-spring-acl-without-xml-file)

and the security configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/authenticate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                .and().addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        authenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        authenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/authenticate");
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My `CustomAuthenticationProvider` class:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = usersService.findOne(username);

        if(user != null && usersService.comparePassword(user, password)){

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(
                            user.getUserRoles().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Here's my `CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`:

```
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        if(!request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(String.format("Authentication method not supported: %s", request.getMethod()));

        try {

            CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationForm form = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getReader(), CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationForm.class);

            String username = form.getUsername();
            String password = form.getPassword();

            if(username == null)
                username = "";

            if(password == null)
                password = "";

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

            setDetails(request, token);

            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new CustomAuthenticationException(exception);
        }
    }

    private class CustomAuthenticationException extends RuntimeException {
        private CustomAuthenticationException(Throwable throwable) {
            super(throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from the above, I have `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler`, `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, `CustomNoRedirectStrategy` and `CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationForm` which I skipped for the sake of this question's length.

And I am using MySQL schema that can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-schema.html#persistent-login-remember-me-schema).

I am adding entries to my acl related tables as follows:

```
INSERT INTO acl_class VALUES (1, com.company.project.domain.users.User)
INSERT INTO acl_sid VALUES (1, 1, "demo")
```

(I have a user with username `demo`)

```
INSERT INTO acl_object_identity VALUES (1, 1, 1, NULL, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO acl_entry VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

But all I am getting is:

```
Denying user demo permission 'READ' on object com.company.project.domain.users.User@4a49e9b4
```

in my

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
```

I am suspecting of several issues here:

1. The `hasPermission` expression: I have substituted it with 'READ' and '1', but to no extent.
2. My database entries are not right
3. I am not implementing a custom permission evaluator. Is this required, or is `expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));` enough?

**Update**

Sample method where `@PostFilter` is used:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
    List<User> find(@Min(0) @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer limit,
                    @Min(0) @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                    @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email,
                    @RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String firstName,
                    @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) String lastName,
                    @RequestParam(value = "userRole", required = false) String userRole) {

        return usersService.find(
                limit,
                page,
                email,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                userRole);
    }
```

**Update #2:**

The question now reflects everything set up in regards to authentication/authorization/ACL.

**Update #3:**

I am now very close to resolve the issue, the only thing left is to resolve this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996579/custom-permissionevaluator-not-called-although-set-as-permissionevaluator-deny

If anyone could help me with that question, I can finally have a write up of what I have went through to resolve this.

Comment: is the method that the @PostFilter is on a public that implements an interface?

Comment: No, it's on a `@RestController` or `@Controller` though. I really suspect of database entries, or a component not being present.

Comment: How does the method look like, where you put the @PostFilter annotation? Do you get any Stacktrace in your server log?

Comment: I'm not that into ACL, but did you maybe mix up the usages of `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostFilter`?  See http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/prefilter-postfilter-in-spring-security

Comment: Not really. As the official documentation (as well as the link you shared) suggests, `@PostFilter` filters the return object based on if the authenticated user has the rights to perform the action stated in the expression. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. The problem is that every object is filtered regardless the ACL entries in the db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the long waited answer:

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) clearly describes:

> To use hasPermission() expressions, you have to explicitly configure a
>   PermissionEvaluator in your application context. This would look
>   something like this:

so basically I was doing in my `AclConfiguration` which extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`:

```
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
        expressionHandler.setPermissionCacheOptimizer(new AclPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclService()));
        return expressionHandler;
    }
```

Which was not getting processed by Spring!

I had to separate `AclConfig` and `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. When there are `@Bean`s defined in the latter, the above method is not getting processed, which might be a bug (if not, any clarification on subject is welcome).

Comment: looks like a little inconsistent behavior to me. Spent hours fixing something I broke while refactoring. Later I realized when trying your solution:
1. was using wrong PermissionEvaluator
2. adding @component worked without adding explicite configuration.

Answer (score 12):

I upgraded my application to use Spring Security 4.2.1.RELEASE then afterwards I started to experience an unexpected access denied in all `@PreAuthorize` annotated methods, which was working just fine before the upgrade.
I debugged the spring security code and I realized that the problem was that all roles to be checked were being prefixed with a default string "ROLE_" regardless of the fact that I had set my default prefix to empty, as shown in the code below.

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .groupSearchBase(ldapProperties.getProperty("groupSearchBase"))
        .groupRoleAttribute(ldapProperties.getProperty("groupRoleAttribute"))
        .groupSearchFilter(ldapProperties.getProperty("groupSearchFilter"))

        //this call used to be plenty to override the default prefix
        .rolePrefix("")

        .userSearchBase(ldapProperties.getProperty("userSearchBase"))
        .userSearchFilter(ldapProperties.getProperty("userSearchFilter"))
        .contextSource(this.ldapContextSource);
```

All my controller methods were annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('my_ldap_group_name')")`, however, the framework was not taking my empty role prefix setting into account and thus it was using *ROLE_my_ldap_group_name* to check the actual role instead.

After I dug deep into the framework's code, I realized that the class `org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` still had the default role prefix set to `"ROLE_"`. I followed up the source of its value and I found out that it was first checking for a declared bean of the class `org.springframework.security.config.core.GrantedAuthorityDefaults` to look for a default prefix during first initialization of the bean `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer`, however, as this initializer bean could not find it declared, it ended up using the aforementioned default prefix.

I believe this is not an expected behavior: Spring Security should have considered the same rolePrefix from ldapAuthentication, however, to solve this issue, it was necessary to add the bean `org.springframework.security.config.core.GrantedAuthorityDefaults` to my application context (I'm using annotation based configuration), as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class CesSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "";
    //... ommited code ...
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(ROLE_PREFIX);
    }

}
```

Maybe you're getting the same problem - I could see that you're using DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler and it also uses the bean GrantedAuthorityDefaults, so if you're using the same Spring Security version as me - 4.2.1.RELEASE you are probably running into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. I am aware that Spring requires `ROLE_` prefix and all my roles start with `ROLE_`. So I hardly think that it should have anything to do with role names. Plus, I don't filter or authorize based on a role, but instead I am using acl to check for permissions on object/user basis.

Comment: Ok, that's what I had to share, I hope you'll figure out the problem, I've never use ACL...

Comment: Thank you for your thorough investigation and a well constructed answer! This solved my problem when I upgraded to spring-security-acl 5.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: Thank you! This totally saved me. I upgraded to spring-boot 2.4.4 (uses spring 5.3.5) from 2.2.7 and suddenly the @Secured annotation would no longer work. Apparently setting the role prefix by extending GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and overriding accessDecisionManager is no longer enough. After setting the grantedAuthorityDefaults as you suggested it works again!

Answer (score 0):

Your data in the DB and your config looks good.  I use `@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")` all the time.

I'd check to make sure your user class that extends UserDetails is returning the same username via getUsername() you have in the db. Along with checking to make sure you security and app are in the same context.

the [hasPermission](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html) method take an [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object as it's 1st param.

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                      Object targetDomainObject,
                      Object permission)
```

The Authentication object is an implementing class, usually of [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html).  So the getPrincipal() method needs to return an object that has a getUserName() method that returns the same thing you have in your DB.

Take a look at [PrincipalSid](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/PrincipalSid.html)

```
public PrincipalSid(Authentication authentication) {
    Assert.notNull(authentication, "Authentication required");
    Assert.notNull(authentication.getPrincipal(), "Principal required");

    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        this.principal = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    }
    else {
        this.principal = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite use `UserDetails` nor `UserDetailsService`. I only return a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` from my class that `implements AuthenticationProvider`. Do I have to for this to work?

Comment: add more details.  it sounds like you don't have the Authentication object setup correctly.

Comment: I agree. I have updated the question to reflect anything that I have configured for authentication/authorization and ACL.

Comment: you should add a toString() method on your user object to it prints out something more useful than the memory location.  eg, the username.

Comment: i'd also double check that UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is being created correctly in CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: `CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` works as it should, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ` is created correctly. `Denying user demo permission 'READ' on object com.company.project.domain.users.User` also means that ACL knows which user is authenticated. But I have discovered that I don't even have any hits on any acl related table in db to check if the user is authorized on a resource. Shouldn't I?

Comment: I figured out I cannot use `AclPermissionEvaluator` with `hasPermission` expression. Please look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996579/yet-another-custompermissionevaluator-aclpermissionevaluator-not-called). Simply every permission is evaluated by `DenyAllPermissionEvaluator`. Other than that, everything seems fine. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `AclPermissionEvaluator` is not respected. The same issue occurred on my way, solved by 2 steps:

1. Created expression handler inside overridden method instead of injecting
2. `WebSecurityConfig` was created in the same class as `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, otherwise, `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` will not work and will not override the handler.